# When a Callcalled contract calls an other contract normally, who is msg.sender?

Tags: security, callcode

If I understand correctly CALLCODE substitute/replace (and not add) the ledger of the target contract with the one the calling contract, isn’t it ?

So that when contract Victor CALLCODE Alice, Alice does no longer use Alice´s ledger but Victor’s ledger, right ?

If true, when contract Alice calls contract Bob normally and when Bob checks `msg.sender`, who is `msg.sender` Alice or Victor ?

Comment: Of course, I forgot to say Alice Bob and Victor are all contract stored at different addresses.

Answer (score -2):

You can not delegatecall normal accounts, only contract accounts.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to say Alice Bob and Victor are all contract.

Comment: But you could guess it by reading the title.

Comment: Apologies, I found the abstraction of using names a bit weird :). 

Delegatecall is merely a forwarder. 

Imagine this: 
User --call--> Contract Victor --delegatecall--> Contract Alice (msg.sender here is Victor) --> delegatecall Contract Bob (msg.sender here still Victor).

Keep in mind delegatecall also forwards the storage. 

Check out this real life example I'm working on : https://github.com/designisdead/blockchain-programmable-incentives/tree/master/contracts

User --Call--> Controller --call-->Storage --Delegatecall-->Proxy --Delegatecall--> Library

Comment: The purpose of the repo is to create upgradeable libraries so our storage delegates calls (with it's storage) to the library that contains the logic. 

More here : https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/proxy-libraries-in-solidity-79fbe4b970fd

Comment: And one more time you didn’t read me. I wrote If true : *when contract Alice calls contract Bob **normally***. So this means `User --call--> Contract Victor --delegatecall or CALLCODE--> Contract Alice (msg.sender here is Victor) --> CALL Contract Bob normally (not Callcode or delegatecall) (who is msg.sender in that case ?)`